# Windows 10 Scheduled Task Powershell Script Unable to Turn off Monitors

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to Windows scripting (I have a linux background), but I attempted to create a Windows version of a udev rule anyway. I cobbled together pieces from various searches to detect when my keyboard/mouse was unplugged (using a USB switch) and to turn off the screen. The powershell script works just fine when I run it myself, but I have yet to get it working using Task Scheduler. I've included the simple script below.

C:\Scripts\keyboard_listener.ps1

```
$query =  "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'"

Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier RemovableDiskDetection -Action {

    $class = $eventArgs.NewEvent.__CLASS
    $device = $eventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Caption

    switch($class)
    {
        __InstanceCreationEvent {
            if ($device -eq "Logitech Gaming HID Device") {
                Write-Host "Inserted, device id: $device"
            }
        }

        __InstanceDeletionEvent {
            if ($device -eq "Logitech Gaming HID Device") {
                Write-Host "Removed, device id: $device"
                (Add-Type '[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I've created the task correctly. The action is `powershell -noexit -file C:\Scripts\keyboard_listener.ps1`. I've even logged the scheduled task to make sure it's running and output stdout/stderr to a log. When I view the log, I can see the "Inserted/Removed" debug messages as expected, but the monitor doesn't turn off. As I mentioned, when I run this command myself, it works as expected. What am I missing?

I've tried running the powershell script from a .cmd file with the same results. I've messed around with the SetExecutionPolicy flag. I don't think either of those matter, though, because I'm able to get the debug output in a log file. I believe this means that the powershell script is executing and that the disconnect/reconnect events are triggering. The only thing that's not happening is my monitor turning off.

Bonus: I haven't looked into this too much, but can I turn the screens back on when the keyboard reconnects? I haven't parsed the turn monitors off command myself to understand exactly how it works, but it would be nice to modify that to turn the screens back on. It's not a priority of mine, however.

Comment: PowerShell is user-session-based, just like most automation languages. PowerShell always runs in the context of the user who started it. In an ST, you must give it a user principal or have it run with higher privilege. See the plethora of Q&A right here on SU, all over the web, and on Youtube, regarding PowerShell and STs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I've verified that the script is running since I can see the log messages output when the keyboard/mouse connects/disconnects. I've tried running the task as SYSTEM as well as my own user (admin account) and both with higher privileges. In all cases I'm able to get the powershell script running as far as I can tell. However, the monitors do not shut off. If you think there's a specific resource that already answers my question please point me in that direction. I've done quite a bit of searching myself and missed it if it exists.

Comment: @postanote I realize I didn't tag you in my comment so you probably didn't get notified so I'm doing it now just in case. Sorry if this double pings you. Thanks